# RSS reader in a single view application

Tags: ios, xcode, rss

I am building a single view application for iPhone, and i would like a RSS reader as a part of the app. I have reed and seen a lot of applications based on navigation based app's with tableview.

I know that it is possible to make a table view in a single view app. But how do i combine the rss reader with the app ? :)

Is there anybody that could help me with some links to tutorials or something like that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ray Wenderlich has a good tutorial here: [How To Make A Simple RSS Reader iPhone App Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial)

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered using a tab bar?  If have had success integrating a RSS reader to my existing app bar having the tab button call the view controller and setting the xib file in the button.

Comment: I dont think this answers his question, how to add a RSS reader.  Thanks for the ideas tho.